# Can we customize the Shoutem Admin UI?

Tags: shoutem

Can we change the look and feel? Is it possible to add more menu options that are more specific to the app? For example, if we want to group our screens in to sections, instead of everything being under the main navigation, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Shoutem Admin UI is customizable through Settings pages. Here is the [tutorial how to write settings pages](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/writing-settings-page). The part of the builder which you're referring to is not customizable, but you can add another `Navigation` screen inside of the `Main navigation`. Use it to group screens.

Check the picture:

[image: Navigation component in Shoutem Builder]